# Highcharts tooltip missing if shadow: true

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I used npm to install highcharts (and highcharts-ng). My highcharts were plotting correctly, but the tooltip was not showing up, and each mouse event was generating an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'd' of null
```

Turning the tooltip off removed this error, but I needed the tooltip. I looked through the traceback and saw a highcharts routine called 'updateShadows'. I figured this was referencing the tooltip shadow, so I added

```
shadow: false
```

to the tooltip. Voila -- the tooltip showed up as expected.

I thought the bug was either not using jquery with highcharts or not using the highchart adapter 'standalone-framwork.js' but I tried all combinations/orders in my gulpfile.js.

Any ideas on why the tooltip shadow would cause this bug? For the most part -- I'm asking this in case someone runs into the same problem...

Comment: Highcharts version 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not intend to answer my own question, but apparently I did not google this thoroughly. Highcharts version 4.2.3 has this as a known issue. I will downgrade to 4.2.1 for now.

https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/issues/84